# How to find who made denial state attack in corda

Tags: corda

Corda non-validating notary doesn't have any information about transaction signatures. Then, when some party in network made denial-of-state attack, how the network find who made that transaction ?

#### About denial-of-state attack

https://www.ingwb.com/media/3024436/solutions-for-the-corda-security-and-privacy-trade-off_-whitepaper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a denial of state attack means in the blockchain context and I'm not able to find anything on it online.

Assuming that means some kind of malicious transaction, remember that generally on a corda network you'll know who's running which nodes (or at least have their keys) so if someone were to submit bad (or malicious) transactions presumably they'd fail verification on the other nodes that would be affected.

You can find out more info on notaries from the docs page here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/key-concepts-notaries.html

Comment: About denial-of-state attack
https://www.ingwb.com/media/3024436/solutions-for-the-corda-security-and-privacy-trade-off_-whitepaper.pdf